# How to make custom class for auto layouts?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout

Like we make custom classes for UIButton and other items of UIKit.

Just we define our layouts in that class and further use them as we do in case of other custom class.

If it can not happen, kindly comment that why it can't be done?

Comment: Maybe you would like to check: http://snapkit.io/docs/

Answer (score 0):

The below extension can be used for your requirement

```
extension UIView {

public func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, left: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, right: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, topConstant: CGFloat = 0, leftConstant: CGFloat = 0, bottomConstant: CGFloat = 0, rightConstant: CGFloat = 0, widthConstant: CGFloat = 0, heightConstant: CGFloat = 0) {

    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    var anchors = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    if let top = top {
        anchors.append(topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: topConstant))
    }

    if let left = left {
        anchors.append(leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: left, constant: leftConstant))
    }

    if let bottom = bottom {
        anchors.append(bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -bottomConstant))
    }

    if let right = right {
        anchors.append(rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: right, constant: -rightConstant))
    }

    if widthConstant > 0 {
        anchors.append(widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: widthConstant))
    }

    if heightConstant > 0 {
        anchors.append(heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightConstant))
    }

    anchors.forEach({$0.isActive = true})
}



public func anchor(centerX: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor? = nil, centerY: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor? = nil, xConstant: CGFloat = 0, yConstant: CGFloat = 0, widthConstant: CGFloat = 0, heightConstant: CGFloat = 0) {

    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    var anchors = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

    if let centerX = centerX {
        anchors.append(centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerX, constant: xConstant))
    }

    if let centerY = centerY {
        anchors.append(centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerY, constant: yConstant))
    }

    if widthConstant > 0 {
        anchors.append(widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: widthConstant))
    }

    if heightConstant > 0 {
        anchors.append(heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightConstant))
    }

    anchors.forEach({$0.isActive = true})
}

}
```

as

```
label.anchor(centerX: view.centerXAnchor, centerY: view.centerYAnchor, xConstant: 20, yConstant: 5, widthConstant: screenSize.width, heightConstant: height1)
```

and

```
label.anchor(top: nil, left: customCell.leftAnchor, bottom: customCell.bottomAnchor, right: customCell.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 22, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 22, widthConstant: width, heightConstant: btnHeigght)
```